# How efficient is Arrays.sort(...) for a 2 Million elements arrays that is already sorted

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting

I need to execute another sorting for an array of 2 Million elements using [Arrays.sort(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte%5B%5D%29) method. In order not to keep another dirty flag like, I was wondering how costly is this method call for an already sorted array.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's only one way to find out.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/232334/best-and-worst-case-for-the-quicksort-algorithm-with-7-elements (which is what sort uses)

Keep your dirty flag.

Comment: Shiva: You mean analysis of the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the content of your array. Sorting primitives uses a dual-pivot Quick Sort, [as per the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29).  This has an amortized complexity of `O(n logn)`, though worst case is `O(n^2)`

Sorting Objects uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)), a modified Merge Sort.  [According to the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), TimSort for a nearly-sorted (or, presumably, sorted) array takes approximately `n` comparisons.

It would be far cheaper still for you to keep a dirty flag rather than suffer the `O(n)` compares.

Comment: Finally, an answer that recognizes that `Arrays.sort()` is implemented differently for primitives and objects... I would say though that whether a dirty flag is useful really depends on what other things are going on.

Answer (score 0):

#### For primitives arrays

```
Best case performance   O(n log n)

Worst case performance  O(n2)
```

For more detailed information read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

#### For Object[] array

```
Worst case performance  O(n log n)
Best case performance   O(n)
```

For more detailed information read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` only uses quicksort for primitives. Object arrays are sorted using mergesort.

Comment: @user3580294 that's write.

Comment: @user3580294 Actually, it's not even really Merge Sort. It's TimSort: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt.

Comment: @Avery Which is a type of mergesort, as stated in the first sentence. But you're right.

Comment: @user3580294 I got distracted and forgot to append that :)

Comment: @deathember your TimSort worst case is wrong. It should be `O(N * log N)`. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Performance

Answer (score -1):

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219777/the-running-time-for-arrays-sort-method-in-java), the sorting runtime will be `O(n*log n)` since `Arrays.sort()` uses a modified version of quicksort, whether the array is already sorted or not.

Comment: Worst case is O(n^2) - it's not always O(n* log n)

Comment: @dotnetnate depends on if you're sorting primitives or objects. Sorting an array of objects uses Timsort (a type of mergesort), and sorting primitives uses quicksort. So worst case could in fact be O(n lg n)

Answer (score -1):

Array.sort() uses the best case complexity scenario of O(n log n) to sort an array by using Merge Sort which in turn uses divide and conquer approach. In the best case where you already have a sorted array the Best Possible Case could be O(n).

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` uses quicksort for primitive arrays.

Comment: Also, you're being contradictory. Does mergesort have best case O(n lg n) or O(n) complexity? Pick one.